# PinholeCameraModel::project3dToPixel is correct?

Tags: ros, image-geometry

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm a beginner about camera geometry.

I would like to understand `PinholeCameraModel::project3dToPixel` function.

[PinholeCameraModel::project3dToPixel](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/image_geometry/html/c++/pinhole__camera__model_8cpp_source.html#l00262)

I derived `uv_rect` like below but the formula are a little different from API.

API tells,

```
uv_rect.x = (fx()*xyz.x + Tx()) / xyz.z + cx();
uv_rect.y = (fy()*xyz.y + Ty()) / xyz.z + cy();
```

I derived,

```
uv_rect.x = (fx()*(xyz.x + Tx())) / xyz.z + cx();
uv_rect.y = (fy()*(xyz.y + Ty())) / xyz.z + cy();
```

Is The unit of `xyz.x` and `Tx()` meter?
If so, my answer is not wrong.

Could you tell me the deriving process of these formula?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/250740/pinholecameramodel::project3dtopixel-is-correct?/) by [baozhang](https://answers.ros.org/users/25430/baozhang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 39 on 2016-12-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's possible there's a bug /transcription error. Can you create a unit test and show it's invalid and see if your solution works correctly? If so I'm sure the maintainer would be interested.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2017-03-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How do you get to that?

```
[U V W]^T = P * [X Y Z 1]^T   (X=xyz.x, Y=xyz.y ...)
```

with `P` something like:

```
[[ fx 0 0 Tx]
 [ 0 fy 0 Ty]
 [ 0 0  1 0]]
```

That gives: `u = U/W + cx` which is what we have in the code no?

---

Originally posted by [Vincent Rabaud](https://answers.ros.org/users/358/vincent-rabaud/) with karma: 1111 on 2017-03-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The function inverts all points at the midpoint so x and y are inverted. This was at least for me very surprising and I sounds wrong to me. So for anybody having a problem with this function try to invert both axis and see if that helps.

---

Originally posted by [Hakaishin](https://answers.ros.org/users/28097/hakaishin/) with karma: 142 on 2018-04-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1